# Bootstrap-select doesn't take id

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I have a problem with the plugin, let me show you html code:

```
{% verbatim %}
  <ul class="hidden-xs">
    {{#each jobs_by_locations}}
      {{#if @last}}
        <li><a href="" class="job-location" data-location-id="{{this.name}}">{{../../link_to_others_title}}</a></li>
      {{else}}
        <li><a href="" class="job-location {{#if @first}}active{{/if}}" data-location-id="{{this.name}}">{{this.name}}</a></li>
      {{/if}}
      {{/each}}
  </ul>

  <select class="visible-xs">
    {{#each jobs_by_locations}}
      {{#if @last}}
        <option data-location-id="{{this.name}}" class="job-location">{{../../link_to_others_title}}</option>
      {{else}}
        <option data-location-id="{{this.name}}" class="job-location {{#if @first}}active{{/if}}">{{this.name}}</option>
      {{/if}}
      {{/each}}
  </select>
{% endverbatim %}
```

So, I have an ul use for desktop screen and a select for mobile.

On my js file, I have problem from there:

```
  $(document).on("click", ".job-location", function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var locationId = $this.data("location-id");
    var pluginHtmlId = $this.closest(".jobs-list-plugins").attr("id");
    ....
```

The problem is that my locationId is undefined.

In fact, when bootstrap-select convert my select, there aren't any data-location-id.
Same thing happen if I use an id instead of the data attribute.

The dropdown menu  contain this after bootstrap-select:

```
<a tabindex="0" class="job-location" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">London</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a>
```

here is the bootstrap-select declaration :

```
$('select').selectpicker({hideDisabled: true});
```

Does anyone have an idea about it ?

Comment: Have your tried `var locationId = $this.attr("data-location-id");` instead of `var locationId = $this.data("location-id");` ?

Comment: have you tried `$this.attr("data-location-id");` ?

Comment: Yes, thanks but it's not working neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, bootstrap-select only reads a few specific data attributes to convert. To achieve what you want, you can make use of `data-content`.

changing you `option` to:

```
<select class="visible-xs">
    {{#each jobs_by_locations}}
      {{#if @last}}
        <option data-content="<span data-location-id='{{this.name}}'>{{../../link_to_others_title}}</span>" class="job-location">{{../../link_to_others_title}}</option>
      {{else}}
        <option data-content="<span data-location-id='{{this.name}}'>{{this.name}}</span>" class="job-location {{#if @first}}active{{/if}}">{{this.name}}</option>
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

and to get the `data-location-id` you'll need to do get it from the span like:

```
$(document).on("click", ".job-location", function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var locationId = $this.children( "span" ).first().attr("data-location-id");
    (...)
```